# Check "list" of entities exists in db ef 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to check if a "list" of entities exists in my database with EF6.

I tried several ways but found no solution.

The most promising was:

```
 public bool ChatWithMembersDoesExistYet(List<User> members)
 {
    return _context.Chats
           .Include(c => c.Members)
           .Any(x => x.Members.Select(y => y.Member)
           .Equals(members));
 }
```

But it always returned false. So I think I am doing something wrong.
Overall I want to check if a chat with the members exists yet. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Equals method on a list calls an Equals for each member of that list so you have to define your own override method in the User Class.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var user= obj as User;

    if (user == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return user.Id == this.Id;
}
```

Comment: That did not work for me. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My helper was `SequenceEquals`:

```
public bool ChatWithMembersDoesExistYet(List<User> members)
{
      return _hankContext.Chats
                         .Any(x => x.Members
                         .Select(y => y.Member)
                         .Select(y => y.Id)
                         .OrderByDescending(z => z)
                         .SequenceEqual(members
                                        .Select(y => y.Id).OrderByDescending(z => z)));
}
```